# Alter session hangs or causes ORA-01013

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, ojdbc, oracle19c

I have the following code block and when the `ALTER SESSION` statement is executed, it either hangs or it throws an ORA-01013 depending on whether we're connecting to Oracle 12r2 or 19.3 and what version of the OJDBC8 driver is being used:

```
try(Connection connection = jdbcConnection.connect(false)) {
  // We now have a java.sql.Connection open to the database at this point
  try(PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(someQuery)) {
    // We not have a prepared statement based on query, the query is irrelevent
    try (Statement s = connection.createStatement()) {
      // The following statement fails with the ORA-01013 error
      s.execute("ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=" + pdbName);
    }
  }
}
```

If I rework this code block to the following, the problem disappears.

```
try(Connection connection = jdbcConnection.connect(false)) {
  // We now have a java.sql.Connection open to the database at this point
  try (Statement s = connection.createStatement()) {
    s.execute("ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=" + pdbName);
  }
  try(PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(someQuery)) {
    // We not have a prepared statement based on query, the query is irrelevent
  }
  // or put the alter session here
}
```

From what I can determine, using Oracle OJDBC8 12.2.0.1, the hang nor the ORA-01013 exception is thrown; however when I migrate to 19.x.0.0, this is where I'm seeing this problem occur.

Is this a bug in the JDBC driver or is there actually a problem with how the code is written that the 12.2.0.1 driver is more lenient with than the later versions?

Comment: Just a thought: are you connecting through a service (service_name in the url) or a SID? Also I assume you're using a global user, right?